# How to migrate dojo/doh tests to intern

Tags: dojo, intern

i have a lot of dojo/doh unit tests, that I would like to migrate to intern/chai. Is there a migration guide or maybe even a converter that can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no converter for automatically migrating tests from DOH to Intern, though if this is something that you are interested in creating, please open a new enhancement ticket, since we would love to have one.

There is also no migration guide, but the path is fairly straightforward in nearly all cases.

### For assertions:

`doh.t(value, message)` → `assert.isTrue(value, message)`
`doh.f(value, message)` → `assert.isFalse(value, message)`
`doh.e(ErrorType, context, fnName, args, message)` → `assert.throws(lang.hitch(context, fnName, arg1, argN), ErrorType, regExp, message)`
`doh.is(expected, actual, message)` → `assert.deepEqual(actual, expected, message)`
`doh.isNot(expected, actual, message)` → `assert.notDeepEqual(actual, expected, message)`

(Chai has [many more assertion types](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/) than DOH)

### For async tests:

`new doh.Deferred` → `this.async(timeout)` (from within a test function)
`doh.Deferred#getTestErrback(callback)` → `InternDeferred#rejectOnError(callback)`
`doh.Deferred#getTestCallback(callback)` → `InternDeferred#callback(callback)`

### For registering tests:

`doh.registerTestType` → create a new test interface (like `tdd`, `bdd`, etc.) and access it from your suites
`doh.register` → use the tdd, bdd, or object interfaces to register suites and tests. you could, in theory, write a new test interface that emulates `doh.register`.

`doh.register` is truly the worst API I have ever used in my life. Nearly every single argument can accept multiple different things so it is very difficult to cleanly explain the migration path for most of these tests. Some signatures, like the `{ runTest, setUp, tearDown }`, do not have direct analogies since in Intern setup and teardown functions are (correctly) per-suite, not per-test.

All these examples assume that `registerSuite` is the identifier for the `intern!object` module.

```
doh.register(groupId, [
  function testA() {},
  function testB() {}
], setupFn, teardownFn);
```

becomes

```
registerSuite({
  name: groupId,
  setup: setupFn,
  teardown: teardownFn,
  testA: function () {},
  testB: function () {}
});
```

---

```
doh.register(groupId, function testFn() {});
```

becomes

```
registerSuite({ name: groupId, testFn: function () {} });
```

---

```
doh.register(groupId, {
  setUp: setupFn,
  tearDown: teardownFn,
  runTest: testFn,
  name: 'myTest'
});
```

does not map cleanly to the Intern model so becomes one of a few different things, depending upon intent.

As a sub-suite:

```
registerSuite({
  name: groupId,
  myTest: {
    setup: setupFn,
    teardown: teardownFn,
    '': testFn
  }
});
```

As a test:

```
registerSuite({
  name: groupId,
  myTest: function () {
    setupFn();
    try {
      testFn();
    }
    finally {
      teardownFn();
    }
  }
});
```

There may be other options as well.

### Miscellany:

`doh.runGroup` → Use the `suites` argument to run specific suites
`doh.togglePaused` →  Use `this.async()` to control flow from within tests
`doh.pause` → Use `this.async()` to control flow from within tests
`doh.run` → Use `this.async()` to control flow from within tests

Obviously Intern has many additional features from DOH as well as a different conceptual model that matches most other test environments so it should be more powerful and easier to use once you get the hang of it.